# What does it mean "The D-Bus daemon is not running"?

Tags: debian, d-bus, blueman

I have a PC with Debian Jessie (amd64) with Gnome as visual environment and I am trying to install Blueman and / or Bluedevil (I thinks these packages are from KDE). I install them from the repositories with `apt-get install blueman`, without apparent errors, but when I run them from the console with `blueman-manager` I get the following error:

> Loading configuration plugins
>
> (blueman-manager: 20757): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect
>   to the D-BUS daemon: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include:
>   the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security
>   policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
>   connection was broken. Skipping plugin GConf gconf-error-quark: The
>   D-Bus daemon is not running   (2) No suitable configuration backend
>   found, exitting

With Bluedevil the answer is very similar.

I have searched for information on the net but I have not found anything that really explains the problem... I think perhaps are some dependencies that are't installed but any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: They probably need to be run from a terminal emulator within a running desktop session - rather than the console. If you need to run things like this from the console, *sometimes* it's sufficient to set an appropriate `DISPLAY` variable; other times you need to set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` explicitly

Comment: What have you done to check and to address the possible causes of the problem _that are given in the message_?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, fool of me, I just tried to open from the applications board (Gnome) and it works perfectly...sorry for the fool question and thanks to @steeldriver !

Answer (score 1):

There are two similar issues on GitHub that suggest that `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` needs to be installed.

[Reference 1](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/547)
[Reference 2](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/650)

Comment: Thanks, for the references, that help me to get an idea, but I'm trying to share the internet connection from my Debian PC to my Android phone...any idea?